# Pytorch sequential data loader

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have looked through the documentation with for ex class IterableDataset and Start / End  but I'm just not good enough to solve this one at the moment.

Training my model with random batches is fine, but using it for predictions I need it to start from min(index) up to max(index). So I wanted to re-use below and change to fit that.

Now it will take random items from the range so I can get duplicate predictions of the same index number. ex range(5) in index 1,2,3,4,5 might give 4,2,2,3,4 not desired 1,2,3,4,5.

```
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
```

DataLoader shuffle = False, then it just takes len / max of index.
I probably need to change the sampler.

```
class CompanyDataset(Dataset):
    

    def __init__(self, csv_name, root_dir, training_length, forecast_window):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file.
            root_dir (string): Directory
        """

        # load raw data file
        csv_file = os.path.join(root_dir, csv_name)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = MinMaxScaler()
        self.T = training_length
        self.S = forecast_window

    def __len__(self):
        # return number of sensors
        return len(self.df.groupby(by=["index"]))

    # Will pull an index between 0 and __len__.
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        # Sensors are indexed from 1
        idx = idx + 1

        # np.random.seed(0)

        start = np.random.randint(0, len(self.df[self.df["index"] == idx]) - self.T - self.S)
        Company = str(self.df[self.df["index"] == idx][["station"]][start:start + 1].values.item())
        index_in = torch.tensor([i for i in range(start, start + self.T)])
        index_tar = torch.tensor([i for i in range(start + self.T, start + self.T + self.S)])
        _input = torch.tensor(self.df[self.df["index"] == idx][
                                  ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"]][
                              start: start + self.T].values)
        target = torch.tensor(self.df[self.df["index"] == idx][
                                  [["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8", "A9", "A10", "A11"]][
                              start + self.T: start + self.T + self.S].values)


       
        scaler = self.transform

        scaler.fit(_input[:, 0].unsqueeze(-1))
        _input[:, 0] = torch.tensor(scaler.transform(_input[:, 0].unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1))
        target[:, 0] = torch.tensor(scaler.transform(target[:, 0].unsqueeze(-1)).squeeze(-1))

        
        dump(scaler, 'scalar_item.joblib')

        return index_in, index_tar, _input, target, station
```

Comment: It is not clear what your dataset structure is and what you are trying to achieve. Your `__getitem__` shouldn't really deal with randomness to pick elements, what's going on here exactly?

Comment: It’s a time series data structure where it groups the input based on station name (str) and then a created index (Int), so station name and index number are linked. So the time series transformer takes the whole created index as batches (now at random) to create forecasts at set ranges. So let’s say I have 5 station names with index 1-5 it now outputs these at random but I want it to be in sequence. Hope that’s makes sense?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, anyhow, to make it simpler: do you know your dataset index to item mapping beforehand?

Comment: Thanks for helping out Ivan, if I can clarify in any way ill do my best. To answer your question yes, the index to item is set at dataprocessing, so its set before it goes to the model.

Comment: Ok good. So given an index, your `__getitem__` function should return the corresponding item, is that the case?

Comment: Correct, I can change the idx to any index number and thats what it will forecast.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand: is it the dataset you're having trouble with or the model?

Comment: Its the model. The __getitem___ returns an index number+1, the torch DataLoader loads shuffle, so if i have 5 index numbers its not certain that it will make a prediction on all 5 since its randomly picking one over every itteration. If i turn of DataLoader shuffle then its makes x predictions on the same idx number. I cant find anything in the docs that has start / end in the DataLoader so its probably that I have to replace above so that Dataloader can have shuffle off and the itteration is made on above code. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.